# Did Kevin Spacey use to look...different?

Tags: make-up

The Richard Pryor/Gene Wilder comedy [*Hear no Evil, See no Evil*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098282/) features a young Kevin Spacey, who has some kind of growth on his face:

[image]

It doesn't serve any plot function, nor is it mentioned or elaborated on.

Other people [around the web](http://www.moviestack.com/posts/104985-kirgos-mysterious-boil) have asked if it was some kind of (real life) [boil or cyst](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-224148.html), that was removed later on in his acting career. Could this be true? There doesn't seem to be any definitive word on this anywhere...

Does anyone know if it was intended to be included in the film? Perhaps a scene was cut that somehow made reference to it, or could someway imply this was makeup?

Comment: You can see it clearly in the limo scene from Working Girl with Melanie Griffith.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Kevin Spacey had a cyst that was removed after it grew to painful proportions. This is outlined in the book by Robin Tamblyn, "[Looking Closer](http://www.robintamblyn.com/images/Looking%20Closer%20Chapter%20Five.pdf)" which is a biography of him.

Here is the quote from the book:

> Spacey does have at least three genuine scars, however. The crease above the
>   lid of his left eye is the legacy of a childhood altercation with a cat named Prince
>   Albert, while the dimple on his left cheek results from a cyst that was removed by
>   surgery in the late Eighties after it grew to painful proportions. In See No Evil, Hear
>   No Evil (1989), it is particularly prominent. He also bears a small “<” shaped furrow
>   above one eyebrow, the mark left by a cardboard coathanger cover thrown at him by
>   Randy during a spat between the siblings in 1968.

Also, if you look at the left side of his face in the below photo, you can see the small roundish scar from where it was removed.

[image]

Comment: Excellent work, JohnP! I knew there was something odd about it in *See No Evil, Hear No Evil*, I couldn't figure out what it was all about...

Comment: He was in the late '80s TV Series Wiseguy. IN this video (at the 1:33 mark) you can see the bump on the left side of his face (would have taken a screen shot but it's hard to freeze at the correct spot): http://www.imdb.com/video/screenplay/vi2632057113/

Answer (score 1):

This is Kevin Spacey in his film debut, [Heartburn (1986)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091188/), from 2 slightly different angles.

[image: A young Kevin Spacey]

[image: Another young Kevin Spacey]

I don't see any indication of a boil or cyst on his face in either of these stills.

Comment: But couldn't it have grown *after* that?

Comment: There is a small cyst present in the top picture, but it's much smaller than the original still posted from See No Evil, Hear No Evil.